# Sign hex digest message with js crypto library

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, cryptography

I need your help. I have C# example how to sign message digest

```
            signatureFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
            string keyText = Convert.ToBase64String(_certificate.PrivateKey);
            byte[] signature = signatureFormatter.CreateSignature(hash);
            return signature;

Later it converts it to base64:

            Convert.ToBase64String(signature)
```

I need to achieve same result with node builtin library crypto, what I wrote:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

...

const sig = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA1');
sig.update(hashValue, 'hex');
sig.end();
const signature = sig.sign(privateKeyString, 'base64');
```

As result I'm getting different signatures for same hash, please help me, how to solve this problem

*** Update ***

Original C# function

```
private byte[] CreateSignature(byte[] hash)
        {
            RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter signatureFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(_certificate.PrivateKey);
            signatureFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
            byte[] signature = signatureFormatter.CreateSignature(hash);
            return signature;
        }
```

Update node.js function

```
        const hashValue= '332a400fdab5b01efcd8407c61987495270ec1b6';
     
        const sig = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA1');
        sig.update(Buffer.from(hashValue, 'utf-8'));
        sig.end();
        const sign = sig.sign(privateKeyString, 'base64');
```

Comment: You are hex encoding the hash value, but you don't do that in the C# code. You'd never sign the hexadecimal digits, you sign the *bytes* themselves. Hex != byte.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thank you very much for your reply, can you please help me fix it? I have updated the question, added the original function and how currently I'm trying to convert it to node.js.  I took "hashValue" variable as converted to hex byte array from C# example

Comment: @MaartenBodewes tried with buffer but it still returns wrong signature